# Addmargins cannot find function in R

Tags: r, scope, eval

The `addmargins` function in R is not able to find functions in a local scope. By this I mean that this does not work:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  bar <- function(y) sum(y)
  addmargins(x, c(1), list(new=bar))
}
foo(matrix(1:20, nrow=4))
# => Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'bar' not found
```

And this does:

```
bar <- function(y) sum(y)
foo <- function(x) {
  addmargins(x, c(1), list(new=bar))
}
foo(matrix(1:20, nrow=4))
# =>
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13   17
# [2,]    2    6   10   14   18
# [3,]    3    7   11   15   19
# [4,]    4    8   12   16   20
# [5,]   10   26   42   58   74
```

How could I use `addmargins` with a variable in a local scope, as in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
foo <- function(x) {

  bar <- function(y) sum(y)
  func <- list(new=bar)
  addmargins(x, c(1), func)
}
foo(matrix(1:20, nrow=4))
```